# Рандомная функция в Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Подскажите, пожалуйста. У меня есть списки номеров полетов в BlazeDemo.Мне нужно чтобы jmeter сам рандомно выбрал из 7 возможных вариантов. С помощью какой функции это делается ?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы про вот эту страницу: https://blazedemo.com/reserve.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то можно вытащить рандомный номер полета с помощью [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cssjquery-extractor)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тогда просто пишете `${random}` там где хотите использовать переменную

еще можно указать Match No. `-1`, тогда JMeter сгенерирует следующие переменные:

```
flight_1=43
flight_2=234
flight_3=9696
flight_4=12
flight_5=4346
flight_matchNr=5
```

и можно будет достать рандомную с помощью комбинаций функций [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) и [__Random()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random)

```
${__V(flight_${__Random(1,${flight_matchNr},)},)}
```

Comment: Да, это оно! Спасибо большое. Я сделала через CSS Selector Extractor. В итоге выбрать рандомные города получилось, а вот сам flight нет. В request пишет везде такое flight=not_found( то что я по дефолту указала)..не пойму что не так, локатор создала и параметр ${flight} тоже